# SQL result with aggregation data

Tags: sql

I need to select some details data from a table and 'create' a new custom record, containing the aggregation of the data selected

For example, I have this data:

```
SELECT abi, cmp, amount, recordid 
FROM mytable;
```

```
abi     cmp     amount     recordId
------------------------------------
01025   25       200         1
01025   25       200         2
01025   25       400         3
99904   04       100         4
99904   04       100         5
```

What I need is to have for each abi column, a new record containing sub totals and aggregation data aggregation like this:

```
abi     cmp     amount     recordId
------------------------------------
01025   25       200         1
01025   25       200         2
01025   25       400         3
>> For Abi 01005 there are 3 records on cmp 25 and total amount 800
99904   04       100         4
99904   04       100         5
>>For Abi 99904 there are 2 records on cmp 04 and total amount 200
```

There is a way to generate these new records using a query?

I checked `rollup()` function but I'm not able to generate the result expected.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

For what you want, `union all` is probably best:

```
select abi, cmp, amount, recordid, 1 as priority
from mytable
union all
select abi, cmp, sum(amount), count(*), 2
from mytable
group by abi, cmp
order by abi, cmp, priority;
```

This leaves the priority in the outer query.  You can get around that using a subquery:

```
select abi, cmp, amount, recordid
from ((select abi, cmp, amount, recordid, 1 as priority
       from mytable
      ) union all
      (select abi, cmp, sum(amount), count(*), 2
       from mytable
       group by abi, cmp
      )
     ) t
order by abi, cmp, priority;
```